# Is there a way in MySQL to select data if two or more columns of different tables are equal?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have created a localhost WordPress site and I have added some extra tables on MySQL phpMyadmin. Now I am trying to make a JSON API that will retrieve data from all those tables. The main tables are `wp_posts` and `wp_users` that were automatically created by WordPress. What I can't achieve is to retrieve the data based on the result of a table I have created (`wp_activities`). For example, if `act_module_id` column of the `wp_activities` table is equal to 1 then go to table `wp_photos` and retrieve the image that has post id equals to `photo_post_id = wp_posts.ID` or else if equals to 2 then just retrieve the post content from `wp_posts`. Below is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_users
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author AND IF(wp_activities.act_module_id = 1) THEN wp_photos.photo_post_id ELSE IF(wp_activities.act_module_id = 2) THEN wp_posts AS activities_module AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'first_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS first_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'last_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS last_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'avatar_hash', meta_value, NULL))AS avatar_hash
    FROM wp_usermeta
    GROUP BY user_id
) pivoted ON pivoted.user_id = wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID
SQL;
```

So, as you can see what I am trying to do is to check what is the module id of `wp_activities` and depends on that to retrieve the data from the rest of the tables, so the result of this IF statement to return on a variable called `activities_module`. If there is any other information you need please let me know. I am new to MySQL and I am trying to understand how it works. Any answer will be appreciated!

**EDIT:** @Jorge Campos answer:

```
<<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM wp_users
CASE WHEN wp_activities.act_module_id = 1 
  THEN wp_photos.pho_post_id
  ELSE wp_posts.post_content
  END
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'first_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS first_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'last_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS last_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'avatar_hash', meta_value, NULL))AS avatar_hash
    FROM wp_usermeta
    GROUP BY user_id
) pivoted ON pivoted.user_id = wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID
SQL;
```

**EDIT2:** I add the whole API file code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once 'wp-connect.php';

$result = [];
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
    wp_users.*,
    pivoted.*,
    CASE WHEN wp_activities.act_module_id = 1
       THEN wp_photos.pho_post_id
       ELSE wp_posts.post_content
    END
FROM wp_users
   LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author 
      AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'   
   LEFT JOIN wp_photos on wp_posts.ID = wp_photos.pho_post_id
   INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'first_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS first_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'last_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS last_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'avatar_hash', meta_value, NULL))AS avatar_hash
    FROM wp_usermeta
    GROUP BY user_id
    ) pivoted ON pivoted.user_id = wp_users.ID
INNER JOIN wp_activities on wp_activities.act_owner_user = wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID
SQL;
foreach (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) as $row) {
    $result[] = [
        'post_id' => $row['ID'],
        'user_id' => $row['post_author'],
        'post' => $row['post_content'],
        'firstName' => $row['first_name'],
        'lastName' => $row['last_name'],
        'username' => $row['user_nicename'],
        'avatar' => $row['avatar_hash'],
        'post_date' => $row['post_date'],
        'post_type' => $row['post_type'],
        'post_title' => $row['post_title'],
        'post_name' => $row['post_name']
    ];
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

**EDIT 3:** @Jorge Campos, When I add another table it throws me again the same error(empty result in the JSON). Check the code bellow:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once 'wp-connect.php';

$result = [];
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
    wp_users.*,
    wp_usermeta.*,
    wp_posts.*,
    wp_photos.*,
    wp_activities.*,
    wp_videos.*,
    
    CASE WHEN wp_activities.act_module_id = 1 AND wp_photos.pho_post_id = wp_posts.ID
    THEN wp_photos.pho_file_name
    WHEN wp_activities.act_module_id = 5 AND  wp_videos.vid_post_id = wp_posts.ID
    THEN wp_videos.vid_url
    END as content
    
FROM wp_users
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
LEFT JOIN wp_photos ON wp_posts.ID = wp_photos.pho_post_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'first_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS first_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'last_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS last_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'avatar_hash', meta_value, NULL))AS avatar_hash
    FROM wp_usermeta
    GROUP BY user_id
) pivoted ON pivoted.user_id = wp_users.ID
INNER JOIN wp_activities on wp_activities.act_owner_id = wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID
SQL;
foreach (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) as $row) {
    $result[] = [
        'post_id' => $row['ID'],
        'user_id' => $row['post_author'],
        'post' => $row['post_content'],
        'firstName' => $row['first_name'],
        'lastName' => $row['last_name'],
        'username' => $row['user_nicename'],
        'avatar' => $row['avatar_hash'],
        'post_date' => $row['post_date'],
        'post_type' => $row['post_type'],
        'post_title' => $row['post_title'],
        'post_name' => $row['post_name'],
        'post_modified' => $row['post_modified'],
        'post_content' => $row['content']
        
    ];
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Comment: Left join both tables `wp_photos` and `wp_posts` and then use `case when` to get the column you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering from my phone, so bare with me here. The solution is to use a left join, something like this:

```
select 
...
case when wp_activities.act_module_id = 1 
  then wp_photos.photo_post_id
  else wp_posts.columnHere end 
...
from wp_users
left join wp_posts on wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author
left join wp_photos on wp_users.ID = wp_photos.photo_post_id
 -- please complete the rest of the query
```

EDIT: Based on your edit here is where you need to fix it:

```
<<<SQL
SELECT 
-- here in the select section is where you 
-- get what you want based on the condition
-- so you can still use the * but it would be better to be
-- a little bit more strict with columns from which table like:
    wp_users.*,
    pivoted.*,
    CASE WHEN wp_activities.act_module_id = 1 
       THEN wp_photos.pho_post_id
       ELSE wp_posts.post_content
    END
FROM wp_users
   LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author 
      AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'   
   LEFT JOIN wp_photos on wp_users.ID = wp_photos.photo_post_id
   INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'first_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS first_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'last_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS last_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'avatar_hash', meta_value, NULL))AS avatar_hash
    FROM wp_usermeta
    GROUP BY user_id
    ) pivoted ON pivoted.user_id = wp_users.ID
-- YOU STILL NEED TO ADD A JOIN WITH wp_activities here 
-- since I dont' know your model I will add it here as a suggestion 
-- and you can correct it based on your model
INNER JOIN wp_activities on wp_activities.activity_user = wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID
SQL;
```

EDIT2: Based on your PHP code, here is a few examples on how to fix it.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once 'wp-connect.php';

$result = [];
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
// you need to be explicit on the column names and 
// and where they should be coming from here at this section
// that is the SELECT section (anything between select and from)
// pay attention here because I do not know your column names
// so I'm simply using something for you to understand
    wp_users.userName as post_author,
    pivoted.first_name,
    pivoted.last_name,
    pivoted.user_nicename,
    pivoted.avatar_hash,
//since you are getting data from two possible tables you have to 
//have the same rule for the columns you are selecting from each
//table, because your PHP code down there is assuming everything
//is coming from the wp_posts table when it could not be the case
// if wp_activities.act_module_id IS NOT 1 so:
    CASE WHEN wp_activities.act_module_id = 1
       THEN wp_photos.pho_post_id
       ELSE wp_posts.ID
    END as contentID,

    CASE WHEN wp_activities.act_module_id = 1
       THEN wp_photos.pho_post_id
       ELSE wp_posts.post_content
    END as content,
// here you need above condition and alias (the: as something part)
// to all below columns that you added on php code
// 'post_date' => $row['post_date'],
// 'post_type' => $row['post_type'],
// 'post_title' => $row['post_title'],
// 'post_name' => $row['post_name']

FROM wp_users
   LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author 
      AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'   
   LEFT JOIN wp_photos on wp_posts.ID = wp_photos.pho_post_id
   INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'first_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS first_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'last_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS last_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'avatar_hash', meta_value, NULL))AS avatar_hash
    FROM wp_usermeta
    GROUP BY user_id
    ) pivoted ON pivoted.user_id = wp_users.ID
INNER JOIN wp_activities on wp_activities.act_owner_user = wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID
SQL;
foreach (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) as $row) {
    $result[] = [
        'post_id' => $row['contentID'],
        'user_id' => $row['post_author'],
        'post' => $row['content'],
        'firstName' => $row['first_name'],
        'lastName' => $row['last_name'],
        'username' => $row['user_nicename'],
        'avatar' => $row['avatar_hash'],
        'post_date' => $row['post_date'],
        'post_type' => $row['post_type'],
        'post_title' => $row['post_title'],
        'post_name' => $row['post_name']
    ];
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Comment: So, as I can understand what I have to do is ti add at the beginning of the query the code you answered above, right?

Comment: It depends on where you want this data. If it is together with the already existing query you posted on your question, then no, you have to change it to add above suggestions (the left joins at the FROM section and the case statement at the SELECT section). But if you want it as a separate you can just use this query as a subquery and join with the existing one.

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I tried your option but when I run the API on Postman nothing is shown up. I see only this "[]"

Comment: Can you edit your question with the changed version please? Then I can look whether there is something missing or wrong.

Comment: I Edited it. Please pay attention to the comments as you will still need to fix the wp_activities one

Comment: hey buddy, it still doesn't work. Let me edit with the whole API I created so you could see some details that may help.

Comment: Based on your code I would say you have a problem with column namings (using aliases), that is you are selecting multiple columns from multiple tables and in the PHP code you are referencing columns that are not in the `SELECT` statement, for instance you have on the PHP code this column: `$row['post_author']` but in the `Select` statement there is no `post_author` whatsoever. I suggested to use the `wp_users.*, pivoted.* ....` because I assumed you knew how to get the right columns you are selecting. I will make a third edit adding a few samples and hopefully you can go from there.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation!! It worked!